# how can i hide my password parameter from request or how can archive encrypt password in react and validate in spring (encrypted in bcrypt)

Tags: reactjs, spring

In my application am using react frontend and server spring.
while login the password showing in request in readable format i want hide them or encrypt them and compare the password with spring (encrypted in bcrypt encoder)

```
  async validateLogin(username, password, userAgent) {
    try {
      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append('username', username);
      formData.append('password', password);
      formData.append('userAgent', userAgent);
      const response = await axios.post(`${this.baseUrl}${this.getAuthentication}`, formData);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
    alert("ERRORD "+error)
      console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to propagate it to the caller
    }
  }
```

In spring am doing as following

```
if (user.isPresent() && new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches(password, user.get().getPassword()))
```

Comment: Why are you doing that yourself? The classes in use indicate the usage of Spring Security, why workaround that instead of use it? You should use an HTTPS connection to send the information, you cannot encrypt it in the client and send it to the server to decrypt. If that is possible you hae a two-way encryption mechanism which aren't safe anyway.

Comment: the attackers (white hat tested ) finding it(password) even using HTTPS @M.Deinum

Comment: I know, but even encrypted only adds a facade of security. You cannot bcrypt encode it as that will create the wrong hash. So the only thing you can do is use base64 encoding (like with http basic auth) which "hides" the password/username.  Or just use basic auth to send the username/password (that is what it was designed for in the first place) instead of your own mechanism.